# Sorting in JCL or COBOL

Tags: cobol, jcl

I have an input file that goes like the following :

```
01 heading of data
inline-data of heading 01
inline-data of heading 01
09 heading of data
inline-data of heading 09
inline-data of heading 09
inline-data of heading 09
inline-data of heading 09
05  heading of data
inline-data of heading 05
```

Expected output :

```
01 heading of data
inline-data of heading 01
inline-data of heading 01
05  heading of data
inline-data of heading 05
09 heading of data
inline-data of heading 09
inline-data of heading 09
inline-data of heading 09
inline-data of heading 09
```

- My break point in my program is the heading.
- I need to sort the whole block of data (heading with its inline-data) to manage the lower numbers first.
- The inline data can vary from 1 to an infinit number of lines
- There is nothing on inline-data lines that indicates that they belong to a heading or another.

(although I am almost certain that there isn't because I searched), I'd like to know if there a way to do this in either JCL or the program ?

Thank you in advance.

SORT in JCL : sorted the headings separately from data,

Breaking point by program (if numeric, and if not, but cannot store the inline data beucase I don't know how many lines can there be for any given heading) : it requires reading the input file multiple times (hundreds of thousands of lines).

Comment: "if there a way to do this in either JCL or the program"? Yes, Cobol has a `SORT` verb.

Comment: Your sort process requires three steps.  1) Read the input file and add a two digit number and a space to all detail lines before writing.  2) Sort the modified input file by the two digit number with equals remaining in input order.  3) Read the sorted file and remove the two digit number and a space from the detail lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shecodes,

Look at the DFSORT smart trick "Sort groups of records" which can found be at

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/smart-dfsort-tricks

In your case assuming that your input has LRECL=80 and RECFM=FB, you can use the following control cards

```
//SYSIN    DD *                                   
  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                       
               BEGIN=(04,08,CH,EQ,C'heading'),    
                PUSH=(81:01,02))                  
                                                  
  SORT FIELDS=(81,02,CH,A),EQUALS                 
                                                  
  OUTREC BUILD=(01,80)                            
/*
```

If your input is RECFM=V or VB then you can use the following control cards

```
//SYSIN    DD *                                  
  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,                       
               BUILD=(01,04,2X,5)),              
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                      
               BEGIN=(10,08,CH,EQ,C'heading'),   
                PUSH=(05:07,02))                 
                                                 
  SORT FIELDS=(05,02,CH,A),EQUALS                
                                                 
  OUTREC BUILD=(01,04,07)                        
/*
```

Answer (score 0):

If the headings are distinguishable, then a three-part key may be used to maintain the order for the inline data within each group while rearranging the heading groups.

```
Three-part key
  Sequence number for the major group (01 heading)
  Heading level (01, 05, 09)
  Sequence number for the original position in the input file
```

For each input record:

If `01 heading`, increment the `sequence number for the major group`.

If `xx heading`, insert the heading number into the heading level.

Increment the `sequence number for the original position`.

Combine the `three-part key` and the input record.

Release the combined record to `SORT`. (Sorting on `ASCENDING three-part key`.)

After the `SORT`:

For each `RETURN`, drop the `three-part key` and `WRITE` the remainder of the sorted (original input) record to the output.